# I still can't find this average value

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the average value of the function $f(x,y,z) = y^2+2(x+1)+z$ over the region in the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ that is bounded above by the plane $z=4x$ and below by the $xy$-plane. I am stuck trying to find the volume of the region because I cannot come up with the bounds.

Comment: Given that you're working with a cylinder, have you tried changing to cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I tried, but I don't think I am doing it correctly at all (I am also considering the shadow in order to get bounds for my last two integrals). I don't think I really know how to convert because I wasn't given clear steps on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cylindrical coordinates are useful here. Recall how we change to cylindrical coordinates:
$$x\mapsto r\cos\theta$$
$$y\mapsto r\sin\theta$$
$$z\mapsto z$$
So, we have $x^2+y^2=r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r^2$. Using the equation for the cylinder given, we know that $x^2+y^2=4=r^2$, so $r=2$ (the negative square root corresponds to the portion of the cylinder below the $xy$-plane, which we don't care about). The bounds on our integral for $z$ are then $0$ and $4r\cos\theta=8\cos\theta$. To find our "lower" integral bound for $r$, we need to solve $4r\cos\theta=0$ for $r$. We find that $r=0$ is the lower bound for the $r$ portion of our triple integral. Likewise, to find the bounds on $\theta$, we need to solve $4r\cos\theta=0$ for $\theta$. That is, we need $\cos\theta=0$. This happens when $\theta=\pm\pi$. So the bounds for the $\theta$ portion of our integral are $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Lastly, we need to change the function we're integrating to cylindrical coordinates. Using the above substitutions, we can write
$$f(r,\theta,z)=r^2\sin^2\theta+2(r\cos\theta+1)+z.$$ Putting this all together and choosing the order of integration carefully, we finally have our triple integral: 
$$\int_{0}^2\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^{8\cos\theta}f(r,\theta,z)dzd\theta dr.$$

Comment: Thank you for the walkthrough. I was overthinking things.